# Lifetime of a value vs lifetime of a borrow

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I managed to write and compile this code:

```
trait Runner {}

struct Human {}

impl Runner for Human {}

struct Player<'a, T>
where
    T: Runner + 'a,
{
    t: &'a T,
}

impl<'a, T> AsRef<T> for Player<'a, T>
where
    T: Runner + 'a,
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T {
        self.t
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

My understanding is that in `struct Player`'s definition, `T` is some concrete type that implements trait `Runner` and `T`'s lifetime is `'a` long. `t` is borrowing `T` and the borrow is also `'a` long.

Is this understanding correct?

In `impl AsRef for Player`'s definition, how does the compiler know that lifetime of the returned borrow to `T`  (from `as_ref`) where `T`'s lifetime is `'a` needs to be less than or equal to `'a`? What is the lifetime of borrow to `self` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust builds successufully if the compiler can assure that the fields of a struct `T` that are references outlive the lifetime of `T`.

With such `Player` definition:

```
struct Player<'a, T>
where
    T: Runner + 'a,
{
    t: &'a T,
}
```

1. We are naming with `'a` the lifetime of `t`.
2. With `T: Runner + 'a` we are declaring that `T` implements `Runner` and that all (eventual) references in `T` must outlive `'a`

For the above considerations if `t` lifetime is `'a` then lifetimes of `Player` values are strictly minor of `'a`.

Lets name `'b` such `Player` value lifetime, then: `'b < 'a`

Avoiding [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) we may rewrite `as_ref` as:

```
fn as_ref<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b T {
    self.t
}
```

The lifetime of borrow to `self` and of returned `&T` is some lifetime strictly minor of `'a`.